# Ferrying OpenTelemetry span/context via org.apache.cassandra.net.Message.Header

Tags: cassandra, jaeger

Lately I endeavored to integrate [Jaeger with Cassandra](https://github.com/smok-serwis/cassandra-jaeger-tracing). However, the only way to reliably sent messages across modes requires specifying a ParamType, which is limited only to an UUID, which is not enough to sent both the 128-bit spanId and parent, nevermind the baggage.

Is there any other way I can reliably send the data to other node using Message.Header?

Or could I alternatively coordinate with the Cassandra team to reserve an integer for the definite use of ferrying OpenTelemetry data?

Comment: I made a blog post regarding my endeavors [here](https://henrietta.com.pl/index.php/2022/10/19/how-do-you-integrate-custom-tracing-with-cassandra/).

Comment: Ok, I've escalated it [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-17981).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was removed in Cassandra 4.0 with the new messaging system introduced.

Will be restored in a patch version of 4.0
Stay tuned.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-17981

Answer (score 0):

I've also love you to check a repository called [cassandra-jaeger-tracing](https://github.com/smok-serwis/cassandra-jaeger-tracing.git).

This is meant to work together to bring Cassandra's tracking inside client requests.

All help is welcome :)